# Prove that an interval of rationals has the same cardinality as the rationals

Tags: cardinals

I am trying to find an answer to this problem 
"Show that the sets $\mathbb Q$ of rational numbers and $A = \{x \in\mathbb Q | 0 \le x \le 1\}$
have the same cardinality"

So, I know we would have to find a bijection from $\mathbb Q$ to $A$. I was thinking of this one :

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x}{x+1},  & \text{if $x$ > - 1} \\[2ex]
1, & \text{if $x$ = -1} \\[2ex]
?, & \text{if $x$ < -1} \\
\end{cases}
$

which I guess it would be well defined (since $x < x+1, \frac{x}{x+1} < 1$) and injective ( $$\frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{x'}{x'+1}  => xx' + x = x'x + x' => x =x'$$). But now I can't find how to define the rationals under -1 to make f surjective !

I tried also to find a bijection from $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ to $A$ (we already saw in class that $|\mathbb N\times \mathbb N| = |\mathbb N| = |\mathbb Q|$)

So far, the closest answer on Internet I could find to my question was on this topic : https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/cardinality-of-an-interval-of-rationals.432232/ , but I can't make sense of it, so I am doing a new topic !

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Note any infinite set has cardinality at least as great as the cardinality of $\Bbb N$.  Note that $\Bbb Q$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb N$.  Note then that the cardinality of a subset of $\Bbb Q$ has cardinality at most as great as the cardinality of $\Bbb Q$ and thus of $\Bbb N$.  So, your set's cardinality is simultaneously greater than or equal and less than or equal to the cardinality of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: "*So, I know we would have to find a bijection from $\Bbb Q$ to $A$*"  No, if you aren't asked to explicitly find a bijection, there is no reason to.  You are better off just finding injections in each direction and applying the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem.  Explicitly writing a bijection can be needlessly confusing.  Simply proving one exists is often far easier.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much !! that is so clear ! aah, I am so dumb, I spent 2 hours trying to find a bijection

Comment: @JMoravitz There is no need to use the result in your first comment: any infinite subset of a countable set is countable. Unlike the general result you indicate (which uses the axiom of choice), this one doesn't, and it also avoids having to invoke the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem.